# I'm trying to get this code I found for draggable SVGs to work

Tags: javascript, svg, draggable

I found some interesting code on [petercollingridge.co.uk](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/interactive-svg-components/draggable-svg-element) for dragging SVGs.

After a while of trying to get it to work in my project, I decided to just try to get Peter's code to run in a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Kushakov/88pocqsr/)

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="400" height="200">
    <style>
    .draggable {
        cursor: move;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
    < ![CDATA[
        var selectedElement = 0;
        var currentX = 0;
        var currentY = 0;
        var currentMatrix = 0;

        function selectElement(evt) {
            selectedElement = evt.target;
            currentX = evt.clientX;
            currentY = evt.clientY;
            currentMatrix = selectedElement.getAttributeNS(null, "transform").slice(7, -1).split(' ');

            for (var i = 0; i < currentMatrix.length; i++) {
                currentMatrix[i] = parseFloat(currentMatrix[i]);
            }

            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove", "moveElement(evt)");
            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout", "deselectElement(evt)");
            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup", "deselectElement(evt)");
        }

        function moveElement(evt) {
            var dx = evt.clientX - currentX;
            var dy = evt.clientY - currentY;
            currentMatrix[4] += dx;
            currentMatrix[5] += dy;
            selectedElement.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", "matrix(" + currentMatrix.join(' ') + ")");
            currentX = evt.clientX;
            currentY = evt.clientY;
        }

        function deselectElement(evt) {
            if (selectedElement != 0) {
                selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmousemove");
                selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseout");
                selectedElement.removeAttributeNS(null, "onmouseup");
                selectedElement = 0;
            }
        }
    ]] >
    </script>
    <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="399" height="199" fill="none" stroke="black" />
    <rect class="draggable" x="30" y="30" width="80" height="80" fill="blue" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 25 20)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)" />
    <rect class="draggable" x="160" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="green" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 103 -25)" onmousedown="selectElement(evt)" />
</svg>
```

I'm still getting the errors I was in my project, those being:

> " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" and "Uncaught ReferenceError: selectElement is not defined "

I read something about invisible characters causing the first problem if you copy/paste code, but I haven't found any.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: Get rid of the `< ![CDATA[` and `]] >`.  Those are no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

Like others said, just remove the CDATA jumbo. Here is an updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/88pocqsr/1/

We've removed `< ![CDATA[` and `]]>`

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
< ![CDATA[
```

to

```
<![CDATA[
```

(remove space between < and !)

and the line

```
]] >
```

to

```
]]>
```

Comment: Thanks RH.  Couldn't get the tags to display right.